# the purpose of using {} after class type c#

Tags: c#, class, curly-braces

I came across this code and i have no idea what it is or what is the purpose.

Class A

```
internal class RequestBase<T>
{
    public RequestBase()
    {
        ID = Helper.GetNextId().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    public RequestBase(string method, T @params)
        : this()
    {
        Method = method;
        Parameters = @params;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string ID { get; private set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "params")]
    public T Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

Class B

```
[DataContract]
internal class AuthenicateRequest
{
    [DataMember(Name = "api_key", IsRequired = true)]
    public string APIKey { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "secret_key", IsRequired = true)]
    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
}
```

So here is the part where i don't understand.

```
var requestObj = new RequestBase<AuthenicateRequest>
                {
                Method = "auth.accessToken",
                Parameters = new AuthenicateRequest
                        {
                        APIKey = api_key,
                        SecretKey = secret_key
                        }
                };
```

Q1: In the section Parameters, how does api_key get pass to ClassB APIKey without doing ClassB.APIKey = api_key?

Q2: Why initiate Parameters = new AuthenicateRequest { APIKey = api_key, SecretKey = secret_key } rather than do Parameters = new AuthenicateRequest(api_key, secret_key)?

I have more questions to ask but i think i better put it in a separate post.

Comment: You should read up on object initializers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called object initializers. They allow you to set properties of a newly constructed objects with a more concise syntax. They behave exactly the same as constructing a new object and then setting those properties one by one as new statements.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

This:

```
var requestObj = new RequestBase<AuthenicateRequest>
                {
                Method = "auth.accessToken",
                Parameters = new AuthenicateRequest
                        {
                        APIKey = api_key,
                        SecretKey = secret_key
                        }
                };
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
var requestObj = new RequestBase<AuthenicateRequest>();
requestObj.Method = "auth.accessToken";
requestObj.Parameters = new AuthenticateRequest();
requestObj.Parameters.APIKey = api_key;
requestObj.Parameters.SecretKey = secret_key;
```

Note that if a constructor requires parameters, these must still be specified inside parentheses no matter which syntax is used, e.g.:

```
var x = new Foo(someParam) {
            SomeProperty = "foobar",
            OtherProperty = 4
        };
```

which is the same as

```
var x = new Foo(someParam);
x.SomeProperty = "foobar";
x.OtherProperty = 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or
>   properties of an object at creation time without having to invoke a
>   constructor followed by lines of assignment statements. The object
>   initializer syntax enables you to specify arguments for a constructor
>   or omit the arguments (and parentheses syntax).

Sample Class:

```
class Cat
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Initialization using Object Initializer:

```
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

Manual Initialization:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.Age = 10;
cat.Name = "Fluffy";
```

**Why use Object Initializers?**

- Sometimes there is no other way, for example when initializing an anonymous type.
- It prevents having many overloads for constructors
- Sometimes it makes code more readable.

Comment: I realize the excerpt is a quote, but its worth noting that this is only the case for objects with default or parameterless constructors. If the object does not have a parameterless constructor, you still have to specify the required arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you're using is called 
[object initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

**Answer to Q1:** This is just the very nature of object initializers. You can imagine the compiler translating

`var request = new AuthenticateRequest { APIKey = api_key, SecretKey = secret_key };`

into

`var request = new AuthenticateRequest();
request.APIKey = api_key;
request.SecretKey = secret_key;`

**Answer to Q2**: Using object initializers does not make sense if you have a constructor available that suits your needs. Then you should just use that.

Answer (score 1):

Construction like `Parameters = new AuthenicateRequest { APIKey = api_key, SecretKey = secret_key }` it is just shorter way to write

```
var param = new Parameters();
param.APIKey = api_key;
param.SecretKey = secret_key;
```

This is called Object Initializers

Answer (score 0):

using braces (`{`,`}`) while instantiating an object allows you to provide values for that object's properties.  So this code:

```
    var authRequest = new AuthenicateRequest
                    {
                    APIKey = api_key,
                    SecretKey = secret_key
                    }
```

is functionally equivalent to this:

```
    var authRequest = new AuthenicateRequest();
    authRequest.APIKey = api_key;
    authRequest.SecretKey = secret_key;
```

To expand on this, you can nest object creation like your example in the question:

```
    var requestObj = new RequestBase<AuthenicateRequest>
    {
        Method = "auth.accessToken",
        Parameters = new AuthenicateRequest
            {
                APIKey = api_key,
                SecretKey = secret_key
            }
     };
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
    var authRequest = new AuthenicateRequest();
    authRequest.APIKey = api_key;
    authRequest.SecretKey = secret_key;

    var requestObj = new RequestBase<AuthenicateRequest>();
    requestObj.Method = "auth.accessToken";
    requestObj.Parameters = authRequest;
```

You can still use any parameterised Constructors if the object has them - e.g.:

```
    MyObject obj = new MyObject("hello") {
                       String2 = "world"
                   };
```

This syntax becomes really useful when using lambda expressions etc.